# Remove SQL Dependencies from SP Standalone Cloned VM

Tags: deployment, environment, configuration

I have made a copy of a standalone SP 2010 VM -> VM_2. I've renamed it, defined another IP. Now VM_1 and VM_2 run simultaneously. I've added following line to hosts file:

```
MY_NEW_IP VM_1 VM_2
```

to redirect the request to itself.

**Problem:** There're still references from VM_2 to SQL Server on VM_1 according to `netstat -a -o`

**Question:** Is there a solution to completely remove these dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rename your SharePoint server as well.

Start -> Run.., `cmd`

> cd "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\"
>
> stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername VM_1 -newservername VM_2
>
> iisreset

Next, go to Central Administration site, System settings => Configure alternate access mappings, and change all the `VM_1` to `VM_2` there.

This should work.

Also, Microsoft provides instructions of renaming SharePoint server with PowerShell, but in our company we tried it and couldn't get it to work. Meanwhile, stsadm command works 100%.

Comment: Thanks I've done this however in Central Administration -> Servers in Farm -> It's referenced to VM_1 and netstat shows opened connections to VM_1. Can a record in a hosts file be a problem?

Comment: Record in hosts file is no longer needed, however, I'm not sure it is the reason. Did you perform the iisreset? We are creating clone VM's almost every day, using this scenario, and all is working...

Comment: Also, could you please run `netstat -ano`, and check, which process is connecting to VM_1? Maybe it is not SharePoint already? Hint: to determine which process is connected to VM_1, go to Task Manager => Processes, View => Select columns..., select PID, and compare this column values with PIDs you got from netstat.

Comment: It's more about SQL processes. Netstat shows that VM_2_IP:1433 has established connection to VM_1_IP:57080 [and some others] Also SP Products Config Wizards shows that SP_Config is mapped to VM_1. And this bothers me.

Comment: All I can recommend is to reboot both VMs. If this would not help, I'll give up :(

Comment: Nevertheless thanks a lot. One more question, what sequence of steps did you use? I considered this one - http://vspug.com/nrdev/2008/07/15/tip-how-to-rename-a-sharepoint-server-machine-name/

Comment: Rename computer => Reboot computer => stsadm -o renameserver => iisreset => fix alternate mappings

Comment: I've re-run the process and it works now )) Thanks for helping

Comment: No problem, feel free to ask any further questions :) And good luck with SharePoint!